# take photo in android emmulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

i tried running "Photo capture example"  in android emulator ,

```
http://labs.makemachine.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/2010_04_09_make_machine_photo_capture.zip
```

when the photocapture example is loaded in android emulator ,
it shows the screen with “No Image” Text and “Take Photo” button. as follows,

[image]

if i click on “Take Photo: Button then a camera window appears with a “black and white boxes” and after that a run time error generated to forcefully close the application.

As far as sd card is concerned i have created it using AVD manager in eclipse.
after that i have set one image file also and mount the sdcard.

But still not be able to take the photo , so please tell me what is require to run this program.

Comment: You will need to obtain an Android device. You cannot adequately take pictures in the emulator.

Comment: can you post the error message

Comment: Can you post the error? It should of showed up in your logcat (./adb logcat).

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the emulator takes dummy pictures exactly as described, with this black and white pattern

Comment: i am getting following error in logcat

FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:916)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)

Answer (score 4):

Are you running on a 2.2 AVD (API level 8)?  The Camera app on the FroYo SDK is horribly, inexcusably [broken](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9376).  Try testing on a different SDK version.

Comment: Yes i am using Android 2.2 sdk. so what else should i use to run this application ?

Comment: Create an AVD with 2.1 as the target.  I doubt you're using any APIs that don't exist in the older version.  You should try to support the oldest SDK that you can.  As you can see in [this chart](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) 30% of all Android users are still stuck with a pre-2.0 OS.